# express.static() not serving files from public folders in router paths that are not "/"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Express.static config:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

File Structure:

```
--public
  --assets
  --js
    --[js scripts]
  --stylesheets
    --[css files]
```

Routes:

```
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shopRoutes')
app.use('/', shopRoutes)

const itemApiRoutes = require('./routes/itemApiRoutes')
app.use('/api/shopitems', itemApiRoutes)

const logSignRoutes = require('./routes/logSignRoutes')
app.use('/account', logSignRoutes)
```

The issue is that all ejs files in the root path at "localhost:3000/" (shopRoutes) calls for the following css file like so and works perfectly fine:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/header.css">
```

Using Express Router, the ejs file at the path "localhost:3000/account/login" calls for the same css file with the exact same syntax but gets the error:

```
Cannot GET /account/login/stylesheets/header.css/
```

Am I not understanding how express.static serves static files or am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a relative URL such as:

```
href="stylesheets/header.css"
```

then the browser adds the path of the web page you're in to that and requests that combined path from your server.  Unless your web page is at the top level of your web site and thus has no path, it will not work properly.  I want to emphasize, this is the browser doing this, not Express.  So, if you're in a web page with this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/account/login
```

And, the browser sees:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/header.css">
```

It will end up combine the path of the web page

```
/account/login
```

with the relative URL you in `<link>` tag and as you've found out, it will request:

```
/account/login/stylesheets/header.css
```

When, `express.static()` sees that URL, that will not match anything in your

```
__dirname + "/public"
```

directory hierarchy so it will not be found.

---

Instead, you want to specify a leading slash:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/header.css">
```

That tells the browser not add any path to the URL and it will send a request to your server for:

```
/stylesheets/header.css
```

When `express.static()` gets that request, it combines that with

```
__dirname + "/public"
```

and will end up looking for a file

```
__dirname + "/public" + "/stylesheets/header.css"`
```

which will be found in your public directory hierarchy and will work.

Comment: Thank you so much! Had no idea how important that leading slash was. Just to make sure I understand this, having a leading slash for "/folder/file" in the url "someurl" says "hey server, im going to check the root directory for the folder, "folder", and get "file. Conversely, not having a leading slash would say, "Hey url, give me the "file" in "url/folder/file"

Comment: @QuanCao - Yep, that little slash tells the browser whether to add the path of the containing web page or not before requesting the URL.